# Nlog Callsite layout render captures complete stack trace

Tags: nlog

I am on nlog 4.5v and when using Callsite layout render, is there a parameter setting that helps to not capture complete stack trace?

I just need namespace, class and method name of the top most stack.

In version 4.7 onwards, documentation mentions that capturestacktrace=false will work but it doesn’t. It prints nothing with set to false.

Couldn’t find any parameters

Answer (score 0):

NLog v4.7.1 extended [${callsite}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-layout-renderer) with option `captureStackTrace=false` to avoid automatically capturing full StackTrace. But then one is required to explictly provide [full StackTrace](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/M_NLog_LogEventInfo_SetStackTrace.htm) for the LogEvent to get output.

NLog v5 introduced an optimized [fluent LogEvent builder](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Logger-API), that uses [caller-member-attributes](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/M_NLog_LogEventInfo_SetCallerInfo.htm) for capturing minimal callsite without using full StackTrace:

```cs
_logger.ForInfoEvent()
       .Message("This is a fluent message {0}.", "test")
       .Property("PropertyName", "PropertyValue")
       .Log();
```